# Checking for null on object before trying to access it

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a better way of writing this?
I dont like the way the null check is in there

```
    editItem.FrameVent =fd.FirstOrDefault(x => x.hardwaretype == 39 
&& x.name.StartsWith("Frame Vent"))==null?null: fd.FirstOrDefault(x => x.hardwaretype == 39 
&& x.name.StartsWith("Frame Vent")).hardwareid;
```

I could do without repeating the query bit

Comment: Since this is not a problem, may be this should be raised in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I might break this into two separate queries for clarity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rewrite it as:

```
editItem.FrameVent = fd.Where(x => x.hardwaretype == 39 && x.name.StartsWith("Frame Vent"))
                       .Select(p => p.hardwareid)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This introduces `O(n)` which can be done without that if you go for local variable.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel And what is the original `O`? ;)

Comment: I agree original is worst ;)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel How can local variable help in terms of `O`?

Comment: Well, `FirstOrDefault` stops iterating as soon as it finds a match, so cache it in `local` then check against null. Assume your match got found in 4 th position of 1000 elements in sequence. `FirstOrDefault` will loop just 4 iterations. but your answer loops 1000 which is `n`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel My query will stop in 4th position as well. And anyway it is still `O(n)` in such case.

Comment: No way, yours is `O(n)` + filtered `O(n)`. By filtered I mean result of `Where` method.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel this answer does not differs from `FirstOrDefault(predicate)` in number of iterations. `Where` will return iterator, which will be projected by `Select` and used by `FirstOrDefault`. As soon as first item will be returned by `Where` iterator, iteration stops

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I believe you underestimate the power of `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Yes my bad, I was under the impression that `Where` will execute fully :( Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it a bit more classic:

```
var result = fd.FirstOrDefault(x => x.hardwaretype == 39 && x.name.StartsWith("Frame Vent"));
editItem.FrameVent = result == null ? null : result.hardwareid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable to simplify

```
var frameVent = fd.FirstOrDefault(x => x.hardwaretype == 39 && x.name.StartsWith("Frame Vent"));
editItem.FrameVent = frameVent==null ? null : frameVent.hardwareid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as some extra information, rather than an answer:

If Microsoft do get around to implementing the "Safe Navigation Operator" ('?.') ([as requested here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3990187-add-operator-to-c)), then the solution would look like this:

```
editItem.FrameVent =
    fd.FirstOrDefault(x => x.hardwaretype == 39 && x.name.StartsWith("Frame Vent"))
    ?.hardwareid;
```

Whether or not introducing this new operator would be a good idea is a matter for debate. :)